# How can i run a function in laravel on the application start?

Tags: laravel

I want to run a specific function which is having the code of listening to the connection of WebSockets (server).

This function should be run at once when the application is started and never stop.
when the application is closed this function should be stopped.

I have a class as Server.php in that i have a function called  reciveData();

Once the application is started reciveData() will accept the connection and send the specific messages to them.

````
```
class Server extends Controller
   {
     public $send_param;
     public $host;
     public $port;

 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->host = env('HOSTADDRESS');
    $this->port = env('PORT');
 }

public function recieveData()
{
    
    set_time_limit(0);
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create 
    socket\n");
    
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $this->host, $this->port) or die("Could 
    not bind to socket\n");
    
    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket 
    listener\n");
    $accept = socket_accept($socket) or die ('not accept the socket 
    connection');   
    do
    {
        $msg = socket_read($accept, 1024) or die('unable to read the 
    input\n');
        $msg = rtrim($msg);
        
        echo "Clinet says:>>".$msg;
        echo '<br><br>';
        //$line = new Chat();
        //echo 'Enter Reply:>> go ahead'.$reply;
        //$reply = $line->readLine();
        //$reply = $this->readLine();
        $reply = 'reply from server go ahead';
        socket_write($accept, $reply, strlen($reply)) or die('unable to write 
     the output\n');
                    
     }while(true);
    
     //socket_close($accept, $socket);

     }```
````

The above is my code, the function in that class should be run as long as the
application starts and stop o application closes.

Comment: every request into your site is booting (starting) the application and when the response is returned the entire thing ends, the process is over ... are you wanting to have a command that is long running or something?

Comment: i think `singleton-pattern`  will give you the solution.....  also are you try something ? ... .

Comment: Yes, @noor singleton-pattern. On application, launch invoke a function for listening to the connection of WebSockets. I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: @lagbox, i don't want any command. wanted from the application itself.

Comment: how are you "launching" the application?

Comment: php artisan serve

Comment: which setups up a webserver to handle HTTP requests ... seems like you want a long running PHP process not a web application that handles HTTP requests (which is a short lived process) ... perhaps something like Laravel websockets (websocket server) ... or your own command

Comment: Yes, WebSockets server. The class is above is the server one. which has to listen to the connections on the laravel project starts.

Comment: make an artisan command if you want to have access the framework and run this code

Comment: Yes, this is a plain PHP script but i am using laravel framework. how can i run this function and debug if the error will occur? This function should be called when the application is launched, i don't want by command. plz help

Comment: that is how you run this ... you make an artisan command that runs this ... this code has nothing to do with any HTTP requests (which is what the framework is for when running in a webserver)

Comment: I have also tried with AppServiceProvider but no luck.

Comment: again, this has nothing to do with HTTP request or routing or any of the things the framework is for in the context of a web server ... this is something that a command is for

Comment: how can i make an artisan command which runs this method?

Comment: you can read the documentation on creating an artisan command ... and that code does not belong in a controller, but since you are not using that class as a controller you can just make an instance of it and call that method, its just PHP

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->app->bind(YourController::class, function ($app) {
    return YourController::yourfunction();
});
```

Paste this inside your AppServiceProvider.php boot method. Use your Controller and function names accordingly.